# Combinations of items with size limit

Tags: combinations, combinatorics, bin-packing

I have a program that given multiple arrays of Integers, it checks if there are duplicate Integers between them. However, this program only works if the sum of the size of the Arrays is less than or equal to 1000. So, to check for duplicates, I need to use the program multiple times with different array combinations.

Example:

Arrays and respective size: A: 550, B: 100, C: 200, D: 400.
I can't put them all in the program at the same time because 550 + 100 + 200 + 400 > 1000.
First we compare arrays A, B and C. Then we compare arrays B, C and D. And we still need to compare arrays A and D.

Given N arrays with sizes x1, x2, ..., xN and knowing that the sum of the size of the 2 largest arrays is smaller than 1000, how can I get the sequence of inputs that minimize the number of executions?

Edit: is this the Bin Packing Problem? We pack the arrays in bins of size 500 and then we compare each bin with the others?

Edit2: This is not the actual problem, I used arrays and integers so it's easier to explain.

Comment: create new empty array then iterate on your given N arrays and sequentially push each value of thus arrays in the empty array if this value doesn't exist in it

Comment: @AdamNorman that defeats the purpose of the problem. I need to use the program with 1000 limit.